# Junit ExpectedException fail with explanatory message

Tags: java, junit, expected-exception

In a junit class, I want to test that an exception is thrown, and if not, provide an explanatory message suggesting what to look for if the test fails. So, something like...

```
    thrown.expect(UnsupportedOperationException.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("an exception message");
    thrown.failureMessage("This method should not be called directly. Be sure to use a subclass or mock that implements the method foo()");
```

Obviously, there is no such method failureMessage(). I cannot be the only one in the world who has ever wanted to implement a failure message. I have not found an example anywhere in my searches.

Note that this is in reference to the Junit4 @Rule and ExpectedException features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit 4.12 has support for custom failure messages (see [release notes](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/doc/ReleaseNotes4.12.md#pull-request-542-customized-failure-message-for-expectedexception)). This failure message is used if your test does not throw an expected exception. Everything else like wrong messages is handled by Hamcrest matchers.

JUnit 4.12 was released 2014-12-04.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom `Matcher`, subclassing `BaseMatcher` overriding `toString()` to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I will have to dig into writing my own custom matcher, I guess. I was hoping to avoid that. I will not mark this as the correct answer for a few days just to be sure someone else doesn't come along with a different solution.